# Check a partial key in typesafe config

Tags: java, config, typesafe

I am using typesafe config to read some initial configurations.

Is there a way to check if a part of key is present in the type config. For example I have the below config:

```
foo {
    bar {
        x = 42
        y = 92
    }    
 }
```

Here I want to check if my conf contains any configuration for foo.bar I don't care if `x` or `y` both are present of either one is present.

I just want to check if configuration for bar is present in config. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7):

Config has method for checking if a path exists

```
config.hasPath("foo.bar");
```

Given the following

```
foo {
    bar {
        x = 42
    }
}

System.out.println(config.hasPath("foo.bar"));
System.out.println(config.hasPath("foo.bar.x"));
```

I get

```
true
true
```

If I remove `x = 42` I get

```
true
false
```

Comment: But it returns false for config.hasPath("foo.bar") , however it returns true for  config.hasPath("foo.bar.x")

Comment: What version of typesafe-config are you using? I just tried this with 1.2.1 and it works as expected in every scenario